# Replace words in string before/after a specific word position? (SQL Statement)

Tags: c#, sql, string, replace

Say I have the following example string:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM table1 ORDER BY c
```

How would I (through string manipulation) change `SELECT a, b, c` to `SELECT COUNT(a)` and also remove the `ORDER BY` clause?

I need to take a generated query in my code and modify it so that I can run the `COUNT()` version of the query and display a label with the number of records marked as printed out of total records.

**EDIT:**

Say I have a more complicated query where I'm performing a union. What do I need to do in order to get the same functionality as asked above? Do I simply change my first `SELECT` clause to `COUNT(*)` or...?

```
SELECT a.memno, 
a.name, 
a.addr1, 
a.addr2, 
a.city, 
a.state, 
a.zip, 
a.sex, 
a.lname, 
a.ssan, 
b.addr1 as old_addr1, 
b.addr2 as old_addr2, 
b.city as old_city, 
b.state as old_state, 
b.zip as old_zip, 
b.timec 

FROM library1.table1 a, library1.table2 b 
WHERE a.memno = b.memno and 
b.groupid = 'P2' and 
b.type = 'B' and 
b.datec = 20131206 AND 
(a.addr1 <> b.addr1 or a.addr2 <> b.addr2 or a.city <> b.city or a. state <> b.state or a.zip <> b.zip) 
UNION 
SELECT 
a.memno, 
a.name, 
a.addr1, 
a.addr2, 
a.city, 
a.state, 
a.zip, 
a.sex, 
a.lname, 
a.ssan, 
b.addr1 as old_addr1, 
b.addr2 as old_addr2, 
b.city as old_city, 
b.state as old_state, 
b.zip as old_zip, 
b.timec 

FROM library2.table1 a, library2.table2 b 
WHERE a.memno = b.memno and 
b.groupid = 'N2' and 
b.type = 'B' and 
b.datec = 20131206 AND 
(a.addr1 <> b.addr1 or a.addr2 <> b.addr2 or a.city <> b.city or a. state <> b.state or a.zip <> b.zip) ORDER BY timec desc
```

Comment: and I guess that you need to do this for any kind of query ? as complex as possible ?

Comment: Basically I need to drop the ORDER BY clause and change everything on the left side of `FROM` to my new part, something along the lines of `SELECT COUNT(a.memno) `.

Answer (score 1):

If the string is really consistent, one approach would be:

```
var input = "SELECT a, b, c FROM table1 ORDER BY c";
var output = input.Replace(
    input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf("FROM") - 1),
    "SELECT COUNT(*)");

var orderByIndex = output.IndexOf("ORDER BY");
var output = output.Replace(
    output.Substring(orderByIndex, output.Length - orderByIndex),
    "");
```

I know here I'm using `SELECT COUNT(*)`, but that's to keep the algorithm simple. If you have the key field readily available via other means, plug it in, but I would say the complication of the parsing isn't worth the breakdown if you have to get it out of the string.

Comment: What about in the case of my EDIT above where I'm doing a UNION? How would I modify it in order to get that same `COUNT(*)` functionality?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be to put the whole query into a subquery for counting (assuming, that you don't care about the ORDER clause):

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (
    SELECT a, b, c FROM table1 ORDER BY c
)
```

Comment: This might work for what I'm after currently, though I have to manipulate the string in C#.